# First do a sum then multiply the value

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I encountered an issue in SQL today that I cannot seem to solve. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

I have the following 2 tables
[image]

Now what I want to get is (labourentries.minutes_worked * price_per_hour / 60) AS price and then to group it by every labourtype and do a SUM(price) so that I would get all totals of the entries per labourtype.

I am using mySql her here is some sample data
[image]

I got some sql this far but couldn't totally solve my issue.

```
SELECT SUM(labourentries.minutes_worked) AS minutes_worked,
       AVG(labourentries.price_per_hour) AS average_price,
       count(labourtypes.id) AS amount,
       labourtypes.labourtype
FROM labourtypes
INNER JOIN labourentries ON labourtypes.id = labourentries.labourtype_id
GROUP BY labourtypes.id
```

Here I tried to do an average of the price_per_hour and then group it but the difference is too big to be reliable.

Anyways thanks for the help in advance.
Cheers!

Comment: Need Clarification...
Please write 2 or 3 rows of labourtypes Table
Please write 2 or 3 rows of labourentries Table
---Then
Please write 2 or 3 rows of what outcome you finally want to see

Comment: Also tag the dbms product used.

Comment: Do you need the `price` for _every_ line in `labourentries` _and_ totals by `labourtypes.id` or just the totals alone? If the latter is the case (and you code suggests so), you may simply use `sum(minutes_worked * price_per_hour / 60) as Price`. See simplified demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce93a/2

Comment: Wow that solved my problem never knew one could do calculations like this in SQL. thanks mate

Comment: Well, yes, `SUM()` (as well as other aggregate functions) accept _arbitrary expressions_ as their arguments (provided the expressions are of correct type).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(PRICE) AS PRICE_PER_LABOURTYPE, A.LABOUR_TYPE  FROM
(SELECT (B.MINUTES_WORKED * B.PRICE_PER_HOUR / 60) AS PRICE, A.LABOUR_TYPE FROM LABOURTYPES A 
INNER JOIN LABORENTERIES B ON A.ID = B.LABOURTYPE_ID)
GROUP BY A.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

After editing the query with Dmitry Egorov's comment I was able to solve the issue by adding this line of code:

```
sum(minutes_worked * price_per_hour / 60) as Price,
```

So my SQL query changed into

```
SELECT SUM(labourentries.minutes_worked) AS minutes_worked,
sum(minutes_worked * price_per_hour / 60) as Price,
count(labourtypes.id) AS amount,
labourtypes.labourtype
FROM labourtypes
INNER JOIN labourentries ON labourtypes.id = labourentries.labourtype_id
GROUP BY labourtypes.id
```